# Needed to parse JSON Objects Present under LinkedList and calculate a field value

Tags: java

I have got a Map with a key and a list of JSONObjects as shown

```
Map<String, LinkedList<JSONObject>> vendorOrdersMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedList<JSONObject>>();
```

I need to calculate price present under each LinkedList of a Vendor , to know which vendor has got the highest price .

```
Map<String, LinkedList<JSONObject>> vendorOrdersMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedList<JSONObject>>();

// For Vendor 1

JSONObject vendor1 = new JSONObject();
vendor1.put("price", "100");

JSONObject vendor2 = new JSONObject();
vendor2.put("price", "200");

LinkedList<JSONObject> list1vendor1 = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();

list1vendor1.add(vendor1);
list1vendor1.add(vendor2);

// For Vendor2

        JSONObject vendor3 = new JSONObject();
        vendor1.put("price", "200");

        JSONObject vendor4 = new JSONObject();
        vendor2.put("price", "300");

        LinkedList<JSONObject> list1vendor2 = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();



        list1vendor2.add(vendor3);
        list1vendor2.add(vendor4);

// Add them to the Map

        vendorOrdersMap.put("Vendor1", list1vendor1);
        vendorOrdersMap.put("Vendor2", list1vendor2);
```

//I started with this but couldn't able to proceed further with this

```
   for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<JSONObject>> entry : vendorOrdersMap.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            LinkedList<JSONObject> jsonobj = entry.getValue();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line was:

```
LinkedList<JSONObject> jsonobj = entry.getValue();
```

After this, iterate over list again like:

```
for(JSONObject obj : jsonobj) {
```

Then get values out of JSONObject like:

```
String price = obj.getString("price");
```

Then do your comparison to calculate highest price.